# How to check if my office 365 app compatible with office 2016 for mac or not

Tags: ms-word, office365, add-in

[image]How to check(make it) if my office 365 app(add-in) compatible with office 2016 for MAC or not

Trying to follow those instructions but no luck:

> Try it out in Word 2016 for Mac Now you can run the add-in you
>   created. Follow these steps to see it in action: Create a folder
>   called “wef” in
>   Users/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.word/Data/Documents/ Put the
>   manifest, BoilerplateManifest.xml, in the wef folder
>   (Users/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.word/Data/Documents/wef) Open
>   Word 2016 on the Mac and click on the Insert tab > My Add-ins drop
>   down. You should see the add-in listed in the drop down. Select it and
>   it will load the add-in.

*This is from website: http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/word-add-ins

Yes I have some issues, but I don't think this should prevent it from being working on word in mac, as it is running fine in word 2016 for windows

*Could this be a reason, I didn't found the path in the instructions 
in my Users folder I didn't found Library folder !! so I created it, and rest of the path, any advice

Comment: Have you tested your app and found some issues?

Comment: @DirkVollmar edited the question to answer you

Comment: What is the exact version of Word for Mac? You'll need at least version 15.21.1

Comment: @DirkVollmar  Version: 15.23 (160611) ,Thank you for trying to help out

Comment: @DirkVollmar could the path issue be the reason?? check my edit

Comment: Yes, the path could be the reason. The path in the documentation you refer to looks wrong, This [article](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac) talks about deploying to `/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/documents/wef`

Comment: @DirkVollmar Thank you for this, I corrected the path now, but again same issue :( my app. didn't show at all !!